# Repeating the question if user input is empty in C#

Tags: c#, loops

I'm having a basic problem with my school code here. The code needs to ask user input as a console program, but I need it to repeat the question when entered an empty field before proceeding. So far I've tried a lot of while-loops, !isStringNullorEmpty, string.lengths, tried to create a function that checks it and some if-statements. I can't get it to work on either one of these. The program proceeds to the end all of the time.

```
System.Console.Write("Give first name");
String firstname = System.Console.ReadLine();

System.Console.Write("Give last name");
String lastname = System.Console.ReadLine();

System.Console.Write("Give date of birth");
DateTime = dt = DateTime.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You should post code with your try which contains loop. Then we can say you where is problem instead of writting whole code.

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
string firstName = null;
Console.WriteLine("Give first name");
while(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(firstName = Console.ReadLine()))
  Console.WriteLine("OMG you had one job as a user of this application, to put in the right value!");
```

You can do the same for `DateTime`

```
Console.Write("Give date of birth");
while (!DateTime.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(),out var dob))
    Console.Write("OMG you had one job as a user of this application, to put in the right value!");
```

---

**Additional Resources**

[DateTime.TryParse Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparse?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent and returns a value that indicates whether the
>   conversion succeeded.

Answer (score 0):

you can write

```
   System.Console.Write("Give first name");
   String firstname = null;
   while(firstname==null || firstname==""){
       firstname = System.Console.ReadLine();
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String lastname = null;

Console.Write("Give last name: ");

while (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname)) {
    lastname = System.Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
            var firstname = string.Empty;
            var lastname = string.Empty;
            var dt = DateTime.MinValue;
            do
            {
                System.Console.Write("Give first name");
                 firstname = System.Console.ReadLine();

            } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(firstname));
            do
            {
                System.Console.Write("Give last name");
                 lastname = System.Console.ReadLine();
            } while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(lastname));


            do
            {
                System.Console.Write("Give date of birth");
                 dt = DateTime.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
            } while (dt != DateTime.MinValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
        bool value = true;

        while (value==true)
        {
            System.Console.Write("Give first name");
            String firstname = System.Console.ReadLine();
            if (firstname == "")
            {
                value = false;
                break;
            }
            System.Console.Write("Give last name");
            String lastname = System.Console.ReadLine();
            if (lastname == "")
            {
                value = false;
                break;
            }
            System.Console.Write("Give date of birth");
             DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(System.Console.ReadLine());
            if (dt.ToString()=="")
            {
                value = false;
                break;
            }
        }
```